# HTML email - webfonts - editor moves style code to bottom

Tags: html, email, editor, google-webfonts

I am adding webfonts to an email template - I add the webfont from google  fonts in the head.

The email html editor I paste the code into - takes the style details and moves them to the end of the email - in turn does not use the web font

any solutions?

here is the code -

note - I have used a few different combinations - including the

---

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin');
</style>

<table style="background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#e6e6e6" class="table_full editable-bg-color bg_color_e6e6e6 editable-bg-image">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="10">
        <tr>
          <td>

            <table style="margin: 0px auto; background-color: rgb(112, 174, 76);" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#303f9f" class="table1 editable-bg-color bg_color_303f9f">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td height="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>

                    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="520" class="table1">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>

                        </tr>



                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" class="text_color_ffffff" align="center">
                            <div class="editable-text"><span style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;"><span style="color:#102743">TITLE</span></span>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 300; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" class="text_color_ffffff" align="center">
                            <div class="editable-text"><span style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;"><span style="color:#102743">SUB HEAD</span></span>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td height="20"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>

            <table style="margin: 0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="table1 editable-bg-color bg_color_ffffff">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td height="10"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>

                    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="520" class="table1">


                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: #102743; font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.5; font-weight: 500; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" class="center_content text_color_102743" align="left">
                            <div style="line-height: 1.5;" class="editable-text"><span style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;">body</span></div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: rgb(112, 174, 76); font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;;" class="text_color_282828" align="center">
                            <div class="editable-text">Interview Date &amp; Time</div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: rgb(16, 39, 67); font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;;" class="text_color_282828" align="center">
                            <div class="editable-text">TEXT</div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>


                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>





                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: rgb(112, 174, 76); font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;;" class="text_color_282828" align="center">
                            <div class="editable-text">text</div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @SuitBoyApps added the code